# std::chrono::duration can be initialized by seconds, but not milliseconds?

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono

Works:
`std::chrono::duration<unsigned long long> test1 = std::chrono::seconds(1);`

Doesn't work:
`std::chrono::duration<unsigned long long> test2 = std::chrono::milliseconds(1);`

Why the difference? Doesn't duration hold sufficient granularity internally?

What's the preferred way to initialize a duration from a value in milliseconds?

Comment: What errors are you seeing with the one that doesn't work?

Comment: *What's the preferred way to initialize a duration from a value in milliseconds?* `auto`.  `auto test2 = 1ms;`

Comment: If I use `auto`, I end up with a `std::chrono::milliseconds`, which apparently then needs to be cast to `seconds` to use with the `chrono::duration` I thought `duration` was unitless? And would that cause granularity problems? Also, it's ugly to need a `duration_cast` for that.

Comment: Durations are kind of unitless, but they have different types and `ratio`s.

Comment: You can come up to speed on `chrono` within an hour by watching this `chrono` tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)'s template parameter list takes two arguments: the type to hold the underlying data, and a `std::ratio` argument representing the exponent of the duration. Types like `std::chrono::seconds` and `std::chrono::milliseconds` are specializations of that template, using `std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1>>` and `std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1, 1000>>` respectively.

If you don't provide a `std::ratio` argument to the type, it will default to `std::ratio<1>`.

As a result, your custom duration type is implicitly taking the form `std::chrono::duration<unsigned long long, std::ratio<1>>`, which makes it *almost* equivalent to `std::chrono::seconds` (the only difference being the unsigned value rather than a signed value), but because its ratio is higher than the ratio provided to `std::chrono::milliseconds`, the class template forbids the assignment/raw conversion. For that case, if you want the assignment to go through, you need to explicitly cast it:

```
typedef std::duration<unsigned long long> my_duration;
//my_duration test1 = std::chrono::milliseconds(1);//Forbidden
my_duration test1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<my_duration>(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)); //Permitted, will be truncated
my_duration test2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<my_duration>(1ms); //Permitted, may be easier to read
```

The `std::ratio` parameter represents the tick size of the duration. The smaller the tick size, the larger the underlying number representing the duration will be. As an example:

```
using seconds = std::chrono::seconds; //std::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1,1>>
using milliseconds = std::chrono::milliseconds; //std::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1,1000>>
using nanoseconds = std::chrono::nanoseconds; //std::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1,1000000000>>

seconds time1 = 5s; //underlying integer value is 5.
milliseconds time2 = 5ms; //underlying integer value is 5.
time2 = time1; //underlying integer value for time2 is 5000, for time1 is still 5.
time2 = 17ms; //underlying integer value is 17.
//time1 = time2; //forbidden; tick size of time2 is smaller than time1
time1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<seconds>(time2); 
//underlying integer value for time1 is 0, due to truncation; time2 is still 17.
nanoseconds time3 = 5ms; //underlying integer value is 5000000.
time1 = 2s; //underlying integer value is 2.
time3 = time1; //underlying integer value is 2000000000.
```

Comment: Can you please describe the truncation? std::chrono::duration is based off of "ticks" which are much smaller, right, so it's still representing 1 millisecond?

Comment: @VoidStar No it will not, hence the requirement for the explicit casting. The tick size of the `duration` is represented by the ratio passed to it. A tick size of `std::ratio<1>` means 1 tick per second. If you need smaller ticks than that (like what's available for `std::chrono::milliseconds` or `std::chrono::nanoseconds`, you need to explicitly specify those smaller tick sizes, like `typedef std::duration<unsigned long long, std::ratio<1, 1'000'000'000>> my_duration` to get a type nearly identical to `std::chrono::nanoseconds`.

Comment: Hmm okay, `std::duration<unsigned long long>` is not nearly as universal/unitless as I thought. I figured the default would be to go to the smallest granularity so it could be more universal. I guess that's the key concept, a `duration` is not unitless at all, but equivalent to `seconds` by default.

Comment: @VoidStar Take a look at the edit I made to my post.